# Inserir dados adicionais, do banco, nas Claims do usuário. Qual o melhor momento ou a forma correta de fazer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2015

Possuo algumas informações extras que preciso adicionar às claims do usuário que são de outras tabelas e classes.

Considerando o método gerado pelo template do ASP.NET MVC com Identity na classe `ApplicationUser`:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{       
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(
            this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);            

        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsKey.ClaimA, "ClaimA"));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsKey.ClaimB, "ClaimB"));
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimsKey.ClaimC, "ClaimC"));

        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Esse que não possui disponível um Contexto do EF e que, também, esse método é gerado em momentos que não existe contexto ainda criado no `request`, como em:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
            .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), 
                // aqui, principalmente ao efetuar login.
                // tentei obter o contexto de 
                // HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext...
                // e obtive um erro por conta de HttpContext.Current 
                // que ainda estava null
                (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)) 
    }
});
```

Na `CreateUserIdentityAsync`, de `ApplicationSignInManager` até pode ter, levando em consideração o momento, que geralmente é requisitado após o login do usuário:

```cs
public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(Usuario user)
{
    return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((AppUserManager)UserManager);
}
```

Levando essas questões em consideração, qual o melhor momento ou uma boa forma de adicionar dados extras às claims, carregados pelo contexto?

Comment: Favoritei. Respondo quando puder.

Comment: Desculpe a demora.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na criação ou edição do usuário. *Claims* são porções de informação que identificam unicamente um usuário. [Um ótimo exemplo está nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32112002/1314276), a qual formatarei para o seu caso.

Repare que `GenerateUserIdentityAsync` não necessariamente atualiza informações na persistência. O método apenas monta o objeto com *Claims* passadas por você. Na verdade acho este exemplo bem ruim, pois tudo o que é adicionado como *Claim* neste exemplo é perdido quando o *Cookie* do usuário expira.

Uma forma mais interessante seria usar o método de extensão `AddOrUpdateClaim`:

Da seguinte forma:

```
    public ActionResult AtualizarUsuarioCorrente()
    {
        User.AddOrUpdateClaim("CPF", "123.456.789-01");
        User.AddOrUpdateClaim("RG", "321.654-85");
        User.AddOrUpdateClaim("CNH", "7132654978");
    }
```

Os métodos de extensão são:

```
    namespace SeuProjeto.Extensions
    {
        public static class ClaimsExtensions
        {
            public static void AddOrUpdateClaim(this IPrincipal principalDoUsuario, string chave, string valor)
            {
                var identity = principalDoUsuario.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                if (identity == null)
                    return;

                // Se a Claim já existe, remove. 
                // Claims não são "atualizáveis". É preciso remover uma
                // Claim antiga para inserir uma nova com o mesmo nome.
                var claimExistente = identity.FindFirst(key);
                if (claimExistente != null)
                    identity.RemoveClaim(claimExistente);

                // Aqui adicionamos uma Claim em banco.
                identity.AddClaim(new Claim(key, value));
                var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
                authenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant = new AuthenticationResponseGrant(new ClaimsPrincipal(identity), new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true });
            }

            public static string GetClaimValue(this IPrincipal principalDoUsuario, string chave)
            {
                var identity = principalDoUsuario.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                if (identity == null)
                    return null;

                var claim = identity.Claims.First(c => c.Type == chave);
                return claim.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Depois de atualizar o usuário, as *Claims* podem ser obtidas assim:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
```