# Autorização em Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Vou tentar ser claro.

Na maioria dos exemplos de autenticação e autorização de acesso em ASP.NET MVC, vejo que o controle de autorização é feito geralmente no `Controller`, com a decoração da própria classe herdada de `Controller`, ou mesmo por decoração das `Actions` com o atributo `Authorize`.
Com isto em prática, todos os itens contidos dentro da minha `view` anexada a essa dita `Action`, vai estar sobre o mesmo nível de autorização.

A dúvida é: Tem alguma forma elegante de fazer que um componente da minha `view` mude de regra de acordo com a `Role` do usuário?

Exemplo simples: Um botão apareça apenas para usuários do tipo Administrador, algo bem específico.

Pensei em algo como, passar o nível de acesso do usuário em uma `viewbag` e fazer uma condição para exibir ou não o dito botão do exemplo com o `Razor`, não sei se essa solução seria a mais adequada. Existe alguma forma mais elegante?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Tem alguma forma elegante de fazer que um componente da minha *view* mude de regra de acordo com a *Role* do usuário?

Sim:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administradores")) { ... }
```

Pode ser necessário escrever um `RoleProvider` ou habilitar o suporte a Roles do ASP.NET Identity, que não é habilitado por padrão.

> Pensei em algo como, passar o nível de acesso do usuário em uma viewbag e fazer uma condição para exibir ou não o dito botão do exemplo com o Razor, não sei se essa solução seria a mais adequada.

Esta é a forma ruim de fazer, e também a mais trabalhosa.

Comment: Tem como fazer com claims?

Comment: @Raphael Sim: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86128/inserir-dados-adicionais-do-banco-nas-claims-do-usu%C3%A1rio-qual-o-melhor-momento/136814#136814