# Sistema web acessado por varias empresas appsettings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP.NET Core, em que cada empresa possui seu banco de dados. A dúvida é: como posso fazer para a empresa A acessar o site colocando usuário e senha e acessar as informações dela, lembrando que existe varias empresas? Existe como mudar o `appsettings.config` para isso, outra alternativa?

Andei vendo a pergunta [Bancos de dados para Clientes diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17095/bancos-de-dados-para-clientes-diferentes), não se seria o correto a fazer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Andei vendo a pergunta [Bancos de dados para Clientes diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17095/bancos-de-dados-para-clientes-diferentes), não se seria o correto a fazer.

Depende. Se você deseja separar os bancos de dados por empresa, é, mas não parece ser o seu caso.

[Estou supondo que você está usando ASP.NET Core Identity](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity). Assim sendo, você precisa estar familiar com [o conceito de *claims*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims), ou seja, de porções de identidade que seu usuário possui.

Para adicionar uma *claim* ao seu usuário, você pode usar:

```
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(user, new System.Security.Claims.Claim("empresa", "A"));
```

Ou:

```
usuario.Claims.Add(new IdentityUserClaim<string> 
{ 
    ClaimType = "empresa", 
    ClaimValue = "A" 
});

contextoIdentity.Entry(usuario).State = EntityState.Modified;
await contextoIdentity.SaveChangesAsync();
```

[Ou esta resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/86128/inserir-dados-adicionais-do-banco-nas-claims-do-usu%C3%A1rio-qual-o-melhor-momento/136814#136814). Tanto faz.

Se for muito necessário que você troque o banco de dados, [você também precisará trocar a *connection string* em tempo de execução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146885/%C3%89-possivel-deixar-connectionstring-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica/149343#149343), provavelmente dentro de um *Action Filter*, ou no [evento `OnActionExecuting` do *Controller*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting(v=vs.118).aspx).

Senão, apenas use o [pacote EntityFramework.DynamicFilters](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters). [Veja aqui como usar](https://github.com/jcachat/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters#changes-in-version-2).

Comment: Opa hoje a empresa so trabalha com sistema desktop, e quer levar isso para a web pegando as informações do banco de dados local, a principio o banco de dados ficara hospedado e alimentado no proprio cliente e replicado as informações para o site quando solicitado, por isso achei que a string de conexão pudesse ser dinâmica para cada login.

Comment: Se é este o caso, não precisa. Um banco de dados apenas resolve tudo.

Comment: Acho que expliquei mal, haverá um conector no banco local da empresa que quando no site precisar algum relatorio, cadastro ou alteração, é acionado esse conector, quando esse conector ficar sem internet algo do tipo a empresa não podera acessar seus dados, como descrevi acima parecia que replicaria para um outro banco mas não.

Comment: Ah, então é melhor você fazer outra pergunta. Você quer um mecanismo de contingenciamento. Não tem nada a ver com o que foi perguntado aqui até então.

Comment: Bom esquecendo esse conector que comentei pra ficar melhor a colocação, no site ele devera apresentar esses banco pra empresa poder escolher ai que esta a duvida, se precisaria algo pra sobrescrever no appsettings ou se teria outra solução ou mesmo duplicando o appsettings ?

Comment: Se você quer escolher o banco em tempo de execução, não é usando o `appsettings.config` que você vai conseguir isso. Vai ter que existir um cadastro de empresas indicando o banco de dados que cada uma usa. Quando o usuário faz o login, o sistema busca a empresa e retorna o banco de dados correto para cada usuário.

Comment: Isso exatamente, so não sei de onde partir, como fazer o retorno do banco digamos que ja tenha o cadastro da empresa como faria para conectar naquele banco de dados, ou trazer a string dela?

Comment: Pois então. Faça outra pergunta e cole o link desta pergunta na outra. Eu coloco outra resposta pra você.

Answer (score 1):

Uma das soluções é fazer a modelagem do banco contendo as chaves estrangeiras para as empresas.

Ex: Você tem o usuário "João" com a chave estrangeira para a empresa "X", logo quando o "João" acessar o sistema você saberá que deverá mostrar as informações da empresa "X", isso é válido para as demais entidades do sistema.

Comment: Exatamente o problema que o banco ficara no proprio cliente que sera replicado as informações para o site quando solicitado a informação no browser,  e como são varios clientes cada um tem um ip externo e o caminho do banco é padrão do sistema.

Comment: Entendi, porém ainda assim não vejo necessidade de múltiplos bancos, você pode ter no cliente um sistema multi empresas que só tenha uma empresa cadastrada, imagino que facilitaria a manutenção e também essa carga no sistema principal de vocês.